# Custom range slider does not work on mobile phone

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a custom price slider. For desktop it works just fine and when I check it in google developer tools for mobile, it works too, but when I open the webpage with my phone, slider stops working properly, it does not change the plan column. How can I debug something like that?
[image: Plan column image]

http://sagemailer-17.eugeneskom.com/

that's the code being used for the slider

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const init = function() {
    const breakpoints = [{
        value: 0,
        step: 12.5,
        stepsSoFar: 0
      },
      {
        value: 200,
        step: 50,
        stepsSoFar: 16
      },
      {
        value: 1000,
        step: 50,
        stepsSoFar: 32
      },
      {
        value: 2000,
        step: 500,
        stepsSoFar: 52
      },
      {
        value: 10000,
        step: 1000,
        stepsSoFar: 68
      },
      {
        value: 30000,
        step: 5000,
        stepsSoFar: 88
      },
      {
        value: 100000,
        step: 10000,
        stepsSoFar: 102
      },
      {
        value: 300000,
        step: 50000,
        stepsSoFar: 122
      },
      {
        value: 1000000,
        stepsSoFar: 136,
        step: 1
      }
    ];
    const pricing = [
      [200, 4, 0.2],
      [500, 10, 0.01],
      [1000, 15, 0.01],
      [2000, 20, 0.005],
      [7000, 50, 0.005],
      [10000, 65, 0.0025],
      [16000, 80, 0.0022],
      [25000, 100, 0.006],
      [30000, 130, 0.002],
      [65000, 200, 0.002],
      [100000, 270, 0.0015],
      [200000, 420, 0.0015],
      [300000, 570, 0.0006],
      [600000, 750, 0.0006],
      [700000, 810, 0.0006],
      [800000, 870, 0.0006],
      [900000, 930, 0.0006],
      [1000000, 990, 0.001]
    ];
    const planBgs = document.querySelectorAll(".StepRangeSlider__trackHeadItem");
    const media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)");
    const minValue = 200;
    const maxStep = breakpoints[breakpoints.length - 1].stepsSoFar;
    const slider = document.getElementById("stepRangeSliderWrap");
    const handle = document.getElementById("rangeSliderHandle");
    const tooltip = document.getElementById("rangeSliderTooltip");
    const plans = document.querySelectorAll(".plan-content .right .content");
    let plansBreakPoints;
    let valueBlock;
    let emailsBlock;
    let isHorizontal;
    let value = 200;
    let step = 18;
    let pressed = false;


    const checkRangeSliderVersion = () => {
      if (media.matches) {
        valueBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".display-price-mob");
        emailsBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".emails-count");
        isHorizontal = false;
      } else {
        valueBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".display-price");
        emailsBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".emails-count");
        isHorizontal = true;
      }

      plansBreakPoints = [
        planBgs[1].getBoundingClientRect()[isHorizontal ? "left" : "top"],
        planBgs[2].getBoundingClientRect()[isHorizontal ? "left" : "top"]
      ];
    };

    checkRangeSliderVersion();
    media.addListener(checkRangeSliderVersion);

    const getPriceForEmailsCount = emails => {
      for (let i = pricing.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (emails === pricing[i][0]) {
          return pricing[i][1];
        }
        if (emails > pricing[i][0]) {
          return (emails - pricing[i][0]) * pricing[i + 1][2] + pricing[i][1];
        }
      }
      return null;
    };

    const getValueForStep = step => {
      const nearest = breakpoints.reduce((prev, curr) =>
        curr.stepsSoFar < step && curr.stepsSoFar > prev.stepsSoFar ?
        curr :
        prev
      );
      const additionalValue = (step - nearest.stepsSoFar) * nearest.step;
      return nearest.value + additionalValue;
    };

    const handleChange = () => {
      const offset = (step / maxStep) * 100;
      handle.style[isHorizontal ? "left" : "top"] = offset + "%";
      tooltip.textContent = Math.floor(value);
      valueBlock.forEach(e => {
        e.textContent = getPriceForEmailsCount(value) + "$";
      });
      emailsBlock.forEach(e => {
        e.textContent = Math.floor(value);
      });
    };

    const handleMove = e => {
      const client = isHorizontal ? e.clientX : e.clientY;
      const sliderRect = slider.getBoundingClientRect();

      let startPosition = isHorizontal ? sliderRect.left : sliderRect.top;
      let endPosition = isHorizontal ? sliderRect.right : sliderRect.bottom;

      if (client <= plansBreakPoints[0]) {
        plans.forEach(e => {
          e.style.display = "none";
        });

        plans[0].style.display = "block";
      } else if (
        client >= plansBreakPoints[0] &&
        client <= plansBreakPoints[1]
      ) {
        plans.forEach(e => {
          e.style.display = "none";
        });

        plans[1].style.display = "block";
      } else if (client >= plansBreakPoints[1]) {
        plans.forEach(e => {
          e.style.display = "none";
        });

        plans[2].style.display = "block";
      }
      if (!client) return;

      let position;
      if (client < startPosition) {
        position = 0;
      } else if (client > endPosition) {
        position = endPosition - startPosition;
      } else {
        position = client - startPosition;
      }
      const currentStep = Math.round(
        (position / (isHorizontal ? sliderRect.width : sliderRect.height)) *
        maxStep
      );
      const currentStepValue = getValueForStep(currentStep);

      if (
        currentStepValue >= minValue &&
        (currentStepValue !== value || currentStep !== step)
      ) {
        value = currentStepValue;
        step = currentStep;
        handleChange();
      }
    };

    const handleTouchMove = e => {
      if (pressed) {
        handleMouseMove(e.touches[0]);
      }
    };

    const handleMouseUp = e => {
      if (pressed) {
        pressed = false;
      }
    };

    const handleMouseMove = e => {
      if (pressed) {
        handleMove(e);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
    window.addEventListener("touchend", handleMouseUp);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      pressed = true;
      handleMove(e);
    });
    slider.addEventListener("touchmove", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      pressed = true;
      handleMove(e.touches[0]);
    });
    handle.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      pressed = true;
      handleMove(e);
    });
    handle.addEventListener("ontouchstart", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      pressed = true;
      handleMove(e.touches[0]);
    });
  };

  init();
};
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem in the question itself.

Comment: My Firefox dev-tools mobile view (Galaxy S20+ Linux) has showing your issue. Seems till 450$ showing "Free".

Comment: @DBS I was trying to minify it, but almost all lines of code are being used to reproduce the issue

Comment: @JaydeepMor looks like it works randomly)

Comment: Works just fine on my touch-supported screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ZqB.gif PS... have you tried to use `"pointer*"` events instead of `"mouse*"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events

Comment: The JS looks fine as an example, but it seems like we'd also need some HTML (and maybe CSS) to reproduce the issue ourselves in a standalone example.

Comment: @DBS will link to the page work or do I need to copy html/css here?
that's the link to the page http://sagemailer-17.eugeneskom.com/

and thank you for reaching me back again)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've tried "pointermove" event instead but still the same issue

Comment: A link to your site is fine in addition to a complete example, but this site generally expects that everything needed to answer the question should be included in the question itself. Here's a related meta question: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1650337)

Comment: Testing the page on my mobile device I can see the issue which you did not described. And that's: the slider "kind of works" but the "touch-position-values" are messed up because the page scrolls as well as you move the slider.

Comment: Another suggestion: Don't use any event on your `handle` element. Just ignore it from any events with CSS `pointer-events: none;`. All you care about is the mouse or finger touching and sliding the parent Element. The handle should be used just as a visual pointer, not an Element that should handle any Events.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I see it now, this issue just popped up but I fixed it, page does not scroll with the slider anymore

Comment: An additional important suggestion: the `"pointermove"` event should be assigned to the `"body"` element, not on the `slider`. The `slider` Element should only handle `"pointerdown"` and `"pointerup"` Events and set the `pressed` boolean variable accordingly. The `"pointermove"` assigned to body should only care about that `pressed` variable. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, to fix a mistake in my previous comment... `pointerup` should be also handled by ˙"body"˙